# What does /usr/src contain in Amazon Ubuntu EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

In the 8 GB ec2 instance it's almost 91% disk full of of 8GB.

I've run `sudo apt-get autoremove` but nothing freed.

I'm curious to know what `/usr/src` directory contains?

Can I simply delete 6 directories with names like 'linux-aws-headers*' in it?

[This procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141630/why-is-usr-src-linux-aws-headers-growing) isn't freeing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are the *headers* for building kernel modules

generally you don't need these unless you're building custom kernel extensions -- but even then you can purge them after you build your extension

here's the code I currently use to purge them (since the name varies so much)

```sh
dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep '^linux-aws-.*headers-.*' |
    xargs sudo apt-get remove --purge -y
```

followed by a `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -y`